# Converting a string number with Dotted Separator in PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable

```
<?php $number = "10000000"; ?>
```

I want convert a string to string number with dotted seperator like this: 10000000 -> 10.000.000

What can i do now? Thanks.

Comment: it wont be an int if it has multiple dots in it. `number_format()`

Comment: Integer is integer, it's when you have to _display_ it that needs the formatting. Try [`number_format`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `number_format()` function formats a number with grouped thousands. For the dotted separator simply use `'.'` as the fourth argument:

```
echo number_format("10000000", 0, ",", "."); //10.000.000
```

Comment: yea, that's the signature of the function I believe :), but the default values don't suit your needs; they group thousands with `','` and indicate the place of decimal point through `'.'`, but when you group thousands with `'.'` then you should differentiate it  with decimal point representation some how, like to display it via `','`, for example :)